# Ant not using ANT_OPTS

Tags: ant

I have following line in my .bash_profile file

```
export ANT_OPTS='-Xmx1024m -Xms1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m'
```

However, when I run ant in one of my projects it doesn't look like it is using above arguments.

This is the command I run

```
ant -f myfile.xml
```

This is how I checked if ant is using ANT_OPTS I added in my .bash_profile file

I captured the running java process and it is using -Xmx512m

Answer (score 2):

Do you see an entry for `ANT_OPTS` when you run the `env` command? If not, you don't have `ANT_OPT` defined in your environment. You may need to put your ANT_OPTS in the `.bashrc` file instead of `.profile` or `.bash_profile`.

Use `ant -d` and see if it's picking up `$ANT_OPTS`. The `ant` command is really a shell script. Sometimes, I put `set -xv` on the top of the `ant` script (temporarily) to see what's going on when it executes. See if that helps you figure out what's going on.

By the way, the `ant` script picks up several *option files* as it executes. In mine, it picks up `/etc/ant.conf`, `$HOME/.ant/ant.conf`, and `$HOME/.antrc`. It may very well be that your `$ANT_OPT` is being overridden by these scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'll need to put it in `bashrc`, not in `bash_profile`: [differences between them](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html).

You need to be sure it was sourced too. If you changed your `bashrc`, the modifications will not be presente until you open a new terminal or run the command:

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Also, take a look in the ant "executable". I don't think it is the problem, but there can be another `-Xmx` passed to the VM, or `ANT_OPTS` are not respected.